# How can I match two different dataframes to show me which rows are matched and which have divergences (showing the divergence)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matching

I have two dataframes and wanted to check if they contain the same data or not.

df1:

```
df1 = [['tom', 10],['nick',15], ['juli',14]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
```

df2:

```
df2 = [['nick', 15],['tom', 10], ['juli',14]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
```

Note that the information between them are exactly the same. The only difference is the row order.

I've created a code to match both dataframes, but it's showing that the dataframes are different on the first two rows:

```
ne = (df != df2).any(1)


ne_stacked = (df != df2).stack()
changed = ne_stacked[ne_stacked]

changed.index.names = ['id', 'col']


difference_locations = np.where(df != df2)
changed_from = df.values[difference_locations]
changed_to = df2.values[difference_locations]

divergences = pd.DataFrame({'df1': changed_from, "df2": changed_to}, index=changed.index)
print(divergences)
```

I am receiving the below result:

```
GRID SPX RECAP
id   col                
0  Name      tom  nick
   Age        10    15
1  Name     nick   tom
   Age        15    10
```

I was expecting to receive:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [df1, df2]
Index: []
```

How I change the code so they can test each row on dataframes to check if they are matched?
And if I was comparing two data frames with different number of rows?

Comment: So what would be the output?

Comment: What is your expected output? Are all your cases going to have the same info in different order?

Comment: Just edited the expected output

Comment: Edited: If I was comparing two data frames with different dataframes rows?

Comment: Why not sort them first then check?